# Howto add records to the Azure Table Storage without the relavant knowledge about such records?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Does anybody know how I can save a record to the azure table storage with the following in mind.

I have to read a CSV file line by line and save it line by line (as an object/record) to the table storage. I only know at runtime how the object (TableServiceEntity) will look like. The CSV can look like anything with a numerous amount of columns. What is the best way to save those records to the Table Storage of Azure?

Is it a good practice to runtime generate classes based on the TableServiceEntity base class? Or should there be an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `WritingEntity` event handler to overwrite the default saving behaviour of a datacontext. Using this event handler, you can then write dynamic columns instead of using reflection.

Take a look at this explanation/sample: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/f57cb566-cc7a-4b31-b1ab-47b6d16604af/